# select all character right of forward slash in sql server?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Am using following query but this to string no form how many number but actually don't know about how many character after '/' and before ?

**String data** like :

```
12/KH/123/1234
```

**output:-**

```
1234
```

**Query:-**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColName,9,CHARINDEX('/',ColName,4))
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Left, Reverse and Charindex` function. Try this.

```
DECLARE @set VARCHAR(100)= '12/KH/123/1234'

SELECT Reverse(LEFT(Reverse(@set), Charindex('/', Reverse(@set)) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It may help you

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('12/KH/123/1234' ,11,CHARINDEX('/','12/KH/123/1234' ,4))
```